# Why do numpy cov diagonal elements and var functions have different values?

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [127]: x = np.arange(2)

In [128]: np.cov(x,x)
Out[128]:
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5]])

In [129]: x.var()
Out[129]: 0.25
```

Why is this the behavior? I believe that covariance matrix diagonal elements should be the variance of the series.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In numpy, `cov`  defaults to a "delta degree of freedom" of 1 while `var` defaults to a ddof of 0.  From the notes to `numpy.var`

```
Notes
-----
The variance is the average of the squared deviations from the mean,
i.e.,  ``var = mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)``.

The mean is normally calculated as ``x.sum() / N``, where ``N = len(x)``.
If, however, `ddof` is specified, the divisor ``N - ddof`` is used
instead.  In standard statistical practice, ``ddof=1`` provides an
unbiased estimator of the variance of a hypothetical infinite population.
``ddof=0`` provides a maximum likelihood estimate of the variance for
normally distributed variables.
```

So you can get them to agree by taking:

```
In [69]: cov(x,x)#defaulting to ddof=1
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5]])

In [70]: x.var(ddof=1)
Out[70]: 0.5

In [71]: cov(x,x,ddof=0)
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0.25,  0.25],
       [ 0.25,  0.25]])

In [72]: x.var()#defaulting to ddof=0
Out[72]: 0.25
```

Comment: Clearer answer than mine :)   It's also worth mentioning that basically all other numpy functions default to `ddof=0`. `numpy.cov` is an exception, probably for historical reasons.

Comment: Thanks for both of you guys! This is indeed confusing. In excel, we have a population version and a sample version for different purposes, which is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `np.cov(x, x, bias=True)` to achieve the same result.

The explanation can be found in [numpy.cov](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) (and in [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction))